# Get partial data of XML file

Tags: c#, xml, xmldocument

I have this xml [file](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/2230967/Movie.xml) which contains information from tagchimp, but the file contains way to much information. How do i only load the information i need. I have found some code:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(path);
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList nodes = root.SelectNodes("movie");

foreach (XmlNode node in nodes)
{
    string date = node["tagChimpID"].InnerText;
    string name = node["locked"].InnerText;
    Console.WriteLine("Id:" + date + " Locked:" + name);
}
```

but it only loads the elements not the child elements, some for example movieTitle or shortDescription

I found a way:

```
public static string Test(string path, XmlElement nodes)
    {
        string Name = "";
        string releaseDate = "";
        XmlNodeList xnList = nodes.SelectNodes("/items/movie");
        XmlNode eNode;
        foreach (XmlNode xn in xnList)
        {
             eNode = xn.SelectSingleNode("movieTags/info/movieTitle");

            if (eNode != null)
            {
                Name = eNode.InnerText;
            }


           eNode= xn.SelectSingleNode("movieTags/info/releaseDate");
                releaseDate = eNode.InnerText;
        }
```

but it's not the most practical way to come by it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using .NET, you might spend some time learning [LINQ to XML](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb387098.aspx), since it sounds like it would do what you want.

There is a lot of online documentation, in particular how to do various basic queries to get information from specific nodes: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb943906.aspx

You could also get the same results with [XPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/87274khy.aspx).

Or you could manually traverse the nodes, although you would have to handle the child nodes properly (as you already discovered).